# Building opencv 3.2.0 with contribution ERROR

Tags: opencv, build, cmake

I am trying to build opencv with opencv_contributions, but I can`t figure out this error at building.

I made cmake like this :

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-master/modules/ ~/opencv-3.2.0/
```

And at the end of building i got this error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_stitching
[100%] Built target opencv_perf_stitching
[100%] Linking CXX shared module ../../lib/cv2.so
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_Z13pyopencv_fromIN2cv4MatxIdLi4ELi4EEEEP7_objectRKT_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/build.make:393: recipe for target 'lib/cv2.so' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/cv2.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:14221: recipe for target 'modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I managed the problem by following this example: [link](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) I also used Git Repository for source code